# Opencv Python - How to seperate the two backgrounds in a cell?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I am engaging in an image processing project and I need some help.

I need to separate the backgrounds in this image.

[Original Blood cell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuPWZ.png)

I could separate the background and the cell using grab cut algorithm.

[Background removed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5k4a.png)

But I couldn't separate the two cell parts; the dark purple part and the light purple parts here. I tried it using grab cut algorithm and morphological operations.

Do I have to use some special method for this..?

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: A simple color segmentation would work in this case, So the steps would be: blur > use cv2.inRange() twice to segment two purple regions > Find contours of each separately > Fill holes if required.

Comment: Thank you very much @ZdaR. This worked well. I need to do this using morphological operations also. I tried it many times. Do you have any idea of doing this using morphological operations like erosion, dilation, opening and closing etc.?